# auto incrementing registration id

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, registration

And I need some help in creating an auto incrementing registration id in my form. It might be numeric or alpha numeric. If it starts like `aaa0001` I have display it in the form. after the first entry it should increment to `aaa0002` and display it in the form. I tried with JSON and PHP, some error there.
that might be aaa0001,aaa0002,......aaa9999....aab0000...

**PHP**

```js
$details = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(`member_id`) FROM `member_details`");
$details = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `member_details` WHERE `member_id` ");

$rows = array();
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($details)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($details);
```

**JSON**

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    //var memid = myObj[0].member_id;
    //memid++;
    //document.getElementById("member_id").value = memid;
    document.getElementById("member_id").value = myObj[0];
    alert(myObj);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/fetch_reg_memid.php?member_id=" + member_id, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: What should happen when you reach `abc9999`? "_some error there_" Yeah, we get that a lot

Comment: after `abc0009` do you have `abc0010` or `abc000a` ?

Comment: `json` is a data interchange format - you mean `javascript`

Comment: i mean javascript, it can be aaa0000, aaa0001, aaa0002....aaa0010.....aaa9999.....aab0000 like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st of all, your 1st query is ok, there is a simpler alternative:

```
$details= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(`member_id`) FROM `member_details`");
$details = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT member_id FROM `member_details` ORDER BY member_id dESC");
```

2nd of all, the extraction from the mysqli should be fixed.
details is an object that you json encode

If there is just one row, you do not need to iterate through the cases...
so

```
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($details);
```

Then `$r['member_id']` should return your member_id:

```
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($details);
print $r['member_id'];
```